# Firebase - retrieve all child keys and child values into separate arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to retrieve all the keys in a child, put them into array, and then retrieve the values for the keys and put it into another array?

[image]

Source code:

```
self.ref?.child("data").child("success").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
   if snapshot != nil {
        // Your answer goes here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Snapshots have two properties.

```
snapshot.key
snapshot.value
```

When using an observer with .value. all of the key: value children are returned in the snapshot. They can be iterated over to capture each key: value pair like this.

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let key = snap.key
        let value = snap.value
        print("key = \(key)  value = \(value!)")
    }
})
```

Keep in mind that the value property could be a string, number, array or another dictionary (snapshot). In the original question it's a String.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should work (with better named variables):

1. Cast the `snapshot.value` as a dictionary
2. Use the dictionary's `.keys` & `.values` properties to retrieve them as `LazyMapCollection` types.
3. Initialise an array with the collections.

**Code:**

```
self.ref?
    .child("data")
    .child("success")
    .child(userID!)
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let keys = Array(data.keys)
            let values = Array(data.values)
            ... // Your code here
        }
    }
```

**Update** - To show example where order is respected:

I would probably save the dictionary to an array, which casts it to type `Array<(key: String, value: Any)>`. Then, you can map it to keys or values and keep the order.

```
... // As above
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let dataArray = Array(data)
            let keys = dataArray.map { $0.0 }
            let values = dataArray.map { $0.1 }
            ... // Your code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem here is that the ordering is lost.

Comment: @Jay Updated the code to reflect your comment - does this fix your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work if the value is another snapshot. It *will* work for this question though, as long as the OP keeps the value a string or number (i.e. a directly orderable value). I like the solution!

Comment: @Jay please if you dont mind please can you help me, check my post related to firebase observer. I don't want complete list data every time only change reflects to specfic field with observer. I am really stuck into it.  link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506034/access-nested-firebase-data-in-swift

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do something similar in my project. Hope this helps and you get the idea

```
var photosList = [String]()
refToObserve?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
        if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: ***your path***).children {
                let myChild = child as! DataSnapshot
                if let myChildValue = myChild.value as? [String:Any] {
                    self.photosList.append(myChildValue["postId"] as! String)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer mapping instead of iteration like me, you can do

```
let keys = snapshot.children.compactMap { ($0 as? DataSnapshot)?.key }
let values = snapshot.children.compactMap { ($0 as? DataSnapshot)?.value }
```